# Am I implementing the SOLID principles the right way?

Tags: solid-principles

This is the first time I am writing a C++ code using SOLID principles. Therefore I do not know if the following sample code implements the principles correctly. My questions follow the code.

I highly appreciate all responses. Thanks!

Here is the sample:

```
class ICustomer
{
public:
        virtual char* GetName() = 0;
        virtual char* GetSurname() = 0;
        virtual char* GetAddress() = 0;
};

class CCustomer : public ICustomer
{
public:
        virtual char* GetName()
        {
               return "Name1";
        }

        virtual char* GetSurname()
        {
               return "Surname1";
        }

        virtual char* GetAddress()
        {
               return "Address1";
        }
};

class IExporter
{
public:
        virtual void Export() = 0;
};

class CExportToExcel : public IExporter
{
public:
        virtual void Export()
        {
               ICustomer* pCustomer = new CCustomer;
               printf("%s, %s, %s\n", pCustomer->GetName(), pCustomer->GetSurname(), pCustomer->GetAddress());
        }
};

class IShopOwner
{
public:
        virtual void Execute() = 0;
};

class CShopOwner : public IShopOwner
{
public:
        virtual void Execute()
        {
            IExporter* pExp = new CExportToExcel;
            pExp->Export();
        }
};

void main()
{
        IShopOwner* pOwner = new CShopOwner;
        pOwner->Execute();
}
```

Questions:

1. Is it a valid SOLID implementation? If no, how it should be.
2. In the sample `ICustomer` has `GetName()`, `GetSurname()` and `GetAddress()`. I want an additional info `GetPhoneNumber()`. Where should I put that in? What changes will it incur?
3. In the sample there is `CExportToExcel`. Now I want an additional class `CExportToHTML` and use it. How should I do that?

Answer (score 1):

The key feedback is to take the dependencies through the concrete class constructors, and take these dependencies as the interfaces not the concrete class, so .. In your object composition root you can decide which actual concrete implementation to pass on to create your objects, ie another product implementation of an interface or just a test mock class for testability purposes. it will also nicely fit with dependency injection pattern and frameworks.

as an example:
change your `CShopOwner` class to have a constructor that takes an `IExporter` object, keep that object as a property and use that inside your `Execute` method. When you are creating your `CShopOwner` object, on run time you can decide what exact concrete implementation of `IExporter` interface to pass it on  ie. `CExportToHTML`.

This should cover your 1st and 3rd questions. About your second question. If `GetPhoneNumber()` would be relevant for all implementation s of `ICustomer`, puristically speaking you should create a new interface still, inheriting from `ICustomer` with one method - `GetPhoneNumber()` - and not change the `ICustomer` interface especially if it is already being used by client code because you are breaking the contract by changing it and may cause issues on the existing clients. On the other hand if you asses the situation and risk you could change the `ICustomer` interface directly and all consumers of it, if this is all your own code which will be much easier. we have all done it :)

Comment: Similarly `ICustomer` implementation should be injected in `CExportToExcel` via constructor or property.

Comment: Yes as I mentioned in the first line of my answer, that applies to all dependencies. About your comment for taking the dependency through a property, I would not recommend that. Dependencies should ideally be taken through object constructor and exposed through Get only properties. (as opposed to Get/Set). That way once you create your object graph on the composition root, you know it will not be changed along the execution flow and dependencies will stay as read only from there on.

Comment: I agree with you, and myself always prefer constructor injection. However, we cannot deny the fact that there are cases when dependency is optional and you could still initialize class without it's dependency because the operations you are going to perform on that class instance don't need that dependency. That's the time when setter/property injection should be considered. I am open to know your thoughts on this. First let me +1 your answer, it's useful.

Comment: Thanks for the upvote, glad that it was useful. I think if a dependency is needed by certain group of methods only and not others, then I would at least reconsider whether the class has too many responsibilities and could it be separated. I would try to avoid writeable properties that hold the dependencies as much as possible but this is software and there are surely cases where you may end up doing that based on the specifics of the situation.